# Select all unlocked cells under ActiveCell in same column

Tags: excel, vba, select

I'm trying to create VBA code which will let me select all unlocked cells in particular Column under ActiveCell.

Trying to resolve it myself, I came across code which partly does the thing:
[Select all blanks cells in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25661659/select-all-blanks-cells-in-a-column)

An also on other page I found code for selecting unlocked cells in worksheet:
https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1279-excel-select-all-unlocked-cells.html

This code selects all rows which are blank, but in fixed column.

```
Dim lr As Long
lr = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("A1:A" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
```

While this will result in choosing all unlocked cells in worksheet:

```
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim OutRng As Range
Dim Rng As Range
On Error Resume Next
Set WorkRng = Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each Rng In WorkRng
    If Rng.Locked = False Then
        If OutRng.Count = 0 Then
            Set OutRng = Rng
        Else
            Set OutRng = Union(OutRng, Rng)
        End If
    End If
Next
If OutRng.Count > 0 Then OutRng.Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

What I expected to get is selecting all cells which are unlocked (they might be filled or not), in column manualy selected in excel.

Example:
Range A1:A4 - is locked, A5 is unlocked, Range A6:A7 is locked, Range A8:A14 is unlocked, A15 is locked, A16:A22 is unlocked
Same for columns B,C,D

Select A5 :Use MACRO, Result> Select A8:A14 & A16:A22,
Select B5 :Use MACRO, Result> Select B8:B14 & B16:B22,

This fill let my either fill selected rows with same content or Delete values from them by one click.

I wasn't able to go pass this:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=3).Activate

Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
```

But this gives me only:
B8:B14 and for range B16:B22 I need to create new MACRO which in the end does not met my requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the code for selecting the unlocked cells is running (and fast enough for your needs), you only have to adjust your `WorkRng`to the desired "column below (including?) your active cell. Please see the following code:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    Dim OutRng As Range
    Dim Rng As Range
    'On Error Resume Next
    'Set WorkRng = Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Set WorkRng = Range(ActiveCell, Cells(Rows.Count, ActiveCell.Column))
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each Rng In WorkRng
        If Rng.Locked = False Then
            'If OutRng.Count = 0 Then
            If OutRng Is Nothing Then
                Set OutRng = Rng
            Else
                Set OutRng = Union(OutRng, Rng)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    If OutRng.Count > 0 Then OutRng.Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```